# Middleware to check token during authorization

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am making an authorization with JWT and this is my middleware to check whether request was send by authorized user or not

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const {secret} = require('../config/app').jwt;

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.get('Token');
    if(!authHeader) {
        return res.status(401).end('Token not provided!')
    }

    const token = authHeader.replace('Bearer ', '');
    try{
        jwt.verify(token, secret);
        if(payload.type !== 'access'){
            return res.status(401).ens('Invalid token type')
        }
    }
    catch(err){
        if(err instanceof jwt.TokenTokenExpired){
            return res.status(401).end('Token expired')
        }
        if(err instanceof jwt.JsonWebTokenError){
            return res.status(401).end('Invalid token');
        }
    }
    next();
}
```

Here token is checked by jwt.berify but i wonder what if someone will try to get access using valid but foreign (for example, admin) token? Should i not only check token for being valid but check if this is token which is refered to THIS user, not someone else? And if i should, what is the best way to do that? To store user_id in token and collate it with the one sent in request? Or otherwise?